# Is there some way to determine the amount of time the user has been "inactive"?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm trying to be able to get a timestamp indicating the last time the user was "active". By "active", I mean one of the following actions has been performed:

- Moved or clicked the mouse.
- Pressed any key on the keyboard.
- Unlocked the lockscreen.

(The reason I want this is because I have a perpetual script running all day, every day, and I want to build a little security mechanism which shuts down the computer if enough time of activity has passed, which probably means I'm "in trouble" somehow.)

Is there such a timestamp kept in Windows which I can pull out with some **terminal command**?

Comment: What do you mean by you're being in trouble? How is this relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a "dead-man's switch" that shuts the PC after extended inactivity, an application such as [WinOFF](http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/WinOFF.php#Download) might work. This would not need to be built into your application.

WinOFF can detect extended idle periods and perform various types of shutdown. BTW, the maximum value for inactivity that can be *entered* is 99 minutes, but the setting in the Registry, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AMP Soft\WinOFF\User idle minutes`, can be changed to larger values and displays correctly when the application is restarted. **Caveat**, extending time this way has not been tested!